# Since Git records the entire content of each file on every commit, how do I work with large files and Git?

Tags: git, github

Is Git effective if my files are huge in terms of Lines of Code and in size? By "huge", I mean text files of about a gigabyte.

Comment: [git-bigfiles](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/git-bigfiles) and [git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/) try to address the issues caused by large files.

Comment: Are you asking about huge binary files or huge text files? And how big does a file have to be for you to consider it "huge"?

Comment: @KeithThompson - huge text files.

Comment: How "huge"? (I'm looking for a number.)

Comment: @KeithThompson about a GB per file.

Answer (score 1):

If it consists of "lines of *code*", it will be probably be fine. You'll usually only run into problems if you store large *binary* files.

Note that git will still use deltas for binary files *within* a pack, but when pushing/pulling the pack that gets sent over the network must be self-contained. So if you have a 10GB file and edit one byte, pushing or pulling will require sending 10GB of data. But if you edit one byte *twice*, it's still only 10GB of data.

While `git-annex` and `git-bigfiles` (which I hadn't heard of until @belwood mentioned it) exist, you're better off asking "do I really need to store huge binary files in my repository?" and see if you can instead store, say, a script that can be used to *generate* a large binary file from a number of smaller, hopefully textual, pieces.